# Movable and editable shape ios

Tags: ios, xcode

i was wondering if there was a way to add a UITextView to the screen and make it both movable and sizable, as well as editable. Until now I gave a UItextView the possibility to be moved around the screen with touches began..., and  the user can resize it using pinch gestures, but I wanted the user to be able to resize it by pulling on any of the 4 corners of the textView (which is like a rectangle), just like you can do with images in Pages (iWork for ipad). Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overlay the corners with buttons and take it from there.